# Python Webscraping: Chinese Site, Odd Response

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I'm trying to scrape this url: https://www.miit.gov.cn/xwdt/szyw

I've scraped a decent amount of sites but never seen a response to a simple request quite like this one:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.miit.gov.cn/xwdt/szyw'

r = requests.get(url)
print(r.text)
```

which gives me:

> u"document.cookie=('*')+('*')+('j')+('s')+('l')+('*')+('c')+('l')+('e')+('a')+('r')+('a')+('n')+('c')+('e')+('*')+('s')+('=')+(-~{}+'')+([2]*(3)+'')+(1+1+'')+((1+[4]>>1)+'')+(-~(3)+'')+((2<<2)+'')+(8+'')+(2+5+'')+(1+6+'')+(-~[]+'')+('.')+(3+5+'')+(0+1+0+1+'')+((2)*[4]+'')+('|')+('-')+(-~{}+'')+('|')+('a')+(1+5+'')+('S')+('D')+('m')+('U')+('z')+('r')+('d')+('m')+('G')+('H')+('j')+('y')+('s')+('G')+('G')+('a')+('B')+('y')+('H')+('h')+('S')+('g')+('d')+('w')+('w')+('%')+((2^1)+'')+('D')+(';')+('m')+('a')+('x')+('-')+('a')+('g')+('e')+('=')+(1+2+'')+(-~[5]+'')+(~~[]+'')+((+false)+'')+(';')+('p')+('a')+('t')+('h')+('=')+('/');location.href=location.pathname+location.search"

Not sure what this is and where to go from here...my usual workflow would be to figure out how the site is structured and go from there, but haven't seen this before...

Comment: `print(r)` given `521` occurs when the origin web server refuses connections from Cloudflare. Security solutions at your origin may block legitimate connections from certain Cloudflare IP addresses.

Comment: The website is running anti-bot techniques which you need to study in order to implement your request, [check-that](https://bpa.st/DIJQ)

Comment: Well, I've been able to get a valid response, you've to use a good ip with zero bad reputation

Comment: Interesting, I've tried on 2 separate IPs now and I've gotten the same response. I wonder if American IPs are blocked?

Comment: Seems you are using a proxy IP! Try to use a Chinese residential IP

Comment: Is there a way to do that through Python or should I just find a chinese proxy

Comment: You can do it via `Python` or whatever, try to find any provider which provide an Chinese proxy.

Comment: I've tried using `https://spys.one/free-proxy-list/CN/` with `r = requests.get(url,proxies=proxies)` same result as before

Comment: you will never ever can be able to call the site using free proxies! those proxies is well known for chines  websites! they are the leader cap for those things